# iOS Radar Display of Map Points

Tags: ios, objective-c, augmented-reality

Background:

Making a geotagging app where people tag places with photos and then people can look at the map and visit these places.

Question:

I want to present a radar screen in addition to the  mapkit view.  This radar would show the points near by locations mapped out on a radar and oriented to the compass of the device.

Existing questions:
- I've seen lots of sdks / plugins suggested.  But, I don't want to pay a license or have any branding.  I am open to an open source solution - but it needs to be mature.  But, I'm cool with developing myself just looking for suggestions on algorithms for laying out the points etc ...

Comment: https://github.com/a1phanumeric/iPhone-AR-Toolkit - This looks like it might be the best open-source option right now.  It's an updated version of the iphone ar kit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radar View like LOVOO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385075/radar-view-like-lovoo)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [ChattAR Location-Chat-Augmented Reality code sample](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chattar). This is open source application, which is:

1. an app;
2. a code sample;
3. a free and open technology which bring social interaction through
   Augmented Reality into your apps.

It contains AR Radar feature which may help you.
It based on http://www.iphonear.org

Also there is a [video guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=AgJZYBoxKz0) how to integrate AR features into your application.

It is completely free

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I've created a unique type radar view to display map coordinates lat,lng on a circular view along with compass functionality. It's available on github.

https://github.com/abm-adnan/Radar

[image: LOVOO like Radar]

Comment: its angle do not correct. please help how can do it?