# Radar like LOVOO app with slider

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, augmented-reality

I am working on an app which has a functionality of RADAR just like LOVOO app. I don't have experience of working on CoreLocation and other location based frameworks.

It would be much appreciated if you could suggest me how should this can be achieved.
What frameworks should i use and how to proceed initially.

Though same question already exists on SO over here my question is same as [Radar View like LOVOO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21385075/1606125)  but its of no use to me thats why i am asking it again.

What i have tried myself so far is, i have lat and long values of points to plot and i have calculated angle and distance between centre point(my location) and other point

```
- (float)angletoCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)second {

//myCurrentLocation is origin

//second is point

float lat1 = DegreesToRadians(myCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude);
float lon1 = DegreesToRadians(myCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude);

float lat2 = DegreesToRadians(second.latitude);
float lon2 = DegreesToRadians(second.longitude);

float dLon = lon2 - lon1;

float y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
float x = cos(lat1) * sin(lat2) - sin(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(dLon);
float radiansBearing = atan2(y, x);
if(radiansBearing < 0.0)
{
    radiansBearing += 2*M_PI;
}

return radiansBearing;
}


-(float)calculateXPointWithLoc:(ARGeoLocation *)loc andDelta:(float)delta{
float angle = radiansToDegrees(delta);
float dpx = (([myCurrentLocation distanceFromLocation:loc.geoLocation])/1000);

if(0<=angle<=90)
    return viewRadar.center.x + sin(angle)*dpx ;
else if(90<angle<=180)
    return viewRadar.center.x + cos(angle-90)*dpx  ;
else if(180<angle<=270)
    return viewRadar.center.x - cos(270-angle)*dpx ;
else if(270<angle<360)
    return viewRadar.center.x - sin(360-angle)*dpx ;

return 0;
}

-(float)calculateYPointWithLoc:(ARGeoLocation *)loc andDelta:(float)delta{
float angle = radiansToDegrees(delta);

float dpx = (([myCurrentLocation distanceFromLocation:loc.geoLocation])/1000);



if(0<=angle<=90)
    return viewRadar.center.y - cos(angle)*dpx ;
else if(90<angle<=180)
    return viewRadar.center.y + sin(angle-90)*dpx ;
else if(180<angle<=270)
    return viewRadar.center.y + sin(270-angle)*dpx ;
else if(270<angle<360)
    return viewRadar.center.y - cos(360-angle)*dpx ;

return 0;
}
```

and then

```
    int i = 0;
    for(ARGeoLocation *loc in coordinates){

    deltaAz = [self angletoCoordinate:loc.geoLocation.coordinate];
    x = [self calculateXPointWithLoc:loc andDelta:deltaAz];
    y = [self calculateYPointWithLoc:loc andDelta:deltaAz];

    [[plots objectAtIndex:i] setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, DIAMETER_PLOT, DIAMETER_PLOT)];
    i++;
    }
```

I am not sure whether x and y are correct or not also if they are correct then how can i change these value with change of slider value.

Comment: I've created a similar LOVOO like Radar view for iOS with slider. It's available on github. https://github.com/abm-adnan/Radar

Comment: Thats really great.. I will sure look the way how u did this but yes i hv also created it but didnt make it public due to NDA signed with my client. Thanks

Comment: if you need any assistance let me know how can I help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the keyword here is **Geofencing**.

Geofencing is the automatic triggering of an action if your device enters or leaves a certain region. For your case your action is to display the profiles of those users who enter the area of your radar.

Basically you need to calculate a circular region (given a radius) and display all other points within your region.

I once found this tutorial which could teach how to do it by yourself:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

I hope it helps!